# Laravel - leftJoin with "as" parametr

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, left-join

I have the following tables:

**main** 
id 
user_id 
host_id

**users** 
id 
room_id

**hosts** 
id 
room_id

**rooms** 
id 
number

As you can see both users and hosts are connected with table rooms. Unfortunately users.room_number = 1, and hosts.room_number = 2. How can I create a query using leftJoin in laravel to distinguish between users.room_number and hosts.room_number? And then how I can refer to each room_number in my foreach loop? 
I have something like this: 
**MainController.php**

```
$main = DB::table('main')
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'main.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('hosts', 'hosts.id', '=', 'main.host_id')
    ->leftJoin('rooms as users_rooms', '=', 'rooms.id', 'users.room_id')
    ->leftJoin('rooms as hosts_rooms', '=', 'rooms.id', 'hosts.room_id')
    ->select('users_rooms.number as u_rooms_number', 'hosts_rooms.number as 
      h_rooms_number')
    ->get();

return view('main.index', ['main' => $index]);
```

**main/index.blade.php**

```
@foreach($main as $element)
    {{ $element->u_rooms_number }}
    {{ $element->h_rooms_number }}
@endforeach
```

Because of both leftJoin with 'rooms as users_rooms' and 'rooms as hosts_rooms' I get an Error "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'rooms.id' in 'on clause'".

Comment: So why do you not change the on join clause from `'rooms'` to `'users_rooms'` and `'hosts_rooms'`?

Comment: because 'rooms' is a table and 'users_rooms' not? And as a first argument there should be a table name which we want to join? But I tried and I got an error that table 'users_rooms' doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error message, because you join twice on the *rooms* table. Your `on` clause therefore cannot identify which table of the two is specified with `'rooms.id'`.

To avoid the conflict you correctly renamed the table joins in your query. Therefore you can use the names as if they were the tables themself.

```
->leftJoin('rooms as users_rooms', '=', 'users_rooms.id', 'users.room_id')
->leftJoin('rooms as hosts_rooms', '=', 'hosts_rooms.id', 'hosts.room_id')
```